# Parsing returned response from Google Translate's translate_a

Tags: java, google-translate

I'm currently trying to translate a String using Google Translate's "free" API.

The [function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) I currenly have is the following:

```
static String sourceLang = "en";
static String targetLang = "de";

public static void translate(String msg) throws Exception {

    msg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, "UTF-8");
    URL url = new URL("http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl="
            + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + msg + "&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8");

    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); 

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

Which returns me, for example

```
[[["Das ist ein Satz","This is a sentence",,,3]],,"en"]
```

or

```
[[["Dies ist ein weiterer Satz mit einigen Symbolen \"$% \u0026 / () = º ~ ª ^","This is another sentence with a few symbols \"$%\u0026/()=º~ª^",,,3]],,"en"]
```

I've been looking into a few JSON parsing methods but I couldn't find a way to convert that to JSON then parse those 3 strings as three String or String[].

Any idea on how should it be properly done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code can do the trick:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    String line = "yourtext";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("m.group(1)=" + m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!
Sorry for the late reply but I only got the reply notification email yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple code to parse the response.

```
var str = responseText.split("]]]]");
for (i=0; i<str.length-1; i++){
    str[i] = str[i].split('","')[0].split('"')[1];
}
str.splice(-1);
str = str.join(" ");
```

Comment: This looks like JavaScript code. I could not find a `splice` method in any of the JDK [classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/index.html). The question is tagged "java" so I think that the OP is asking for Java code (and **not** JavaScript code).